# NTier Application - creating NON DLL Classes

Tags: visual-studio, reference, n-tier-architecture

Im trying to create an NTier Application. I have created a directory called:

(1) App_Code/Business/Products.cs
Inside, contains:

```
    using GridviewExample.App_Code.DAL;
    namespace GridViewExample.App_Code.Business {

        public class Products
        {

            public string void GetProducts(string hi)
            {
                return GridViewExample.App_Code.DAL.GetProducts(hi)


            }
        }

    }
```

&
(2) App_Code/Business/Products.cs

```
namespace GridViewExample.App_Code.DAL{

    public class Products
    {

        public string void GetProducts(string hi)
        {
            return hi


        }
    }

}
```

However, when i try referencing these files in my website (local), it cant find it in using the using statement (at the top of the code). Is there anyway I can run it without creating DLL's of these classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app is a web site as opposed to web project. In web site applications the code exist in 2 places - in the AppCode directory as well as in some other directories.

The difference is that everything from directories other than AppCode is compiled upfront, while the AppCode stuff is compiled upon the app strtup. Because of this classes from the AppCode are not accessible from the rest of the app. In other words you should not place anything but the code-behinds in the AppCode directory.

In general I would stay away from web sites and build all my web apps as web projects